# How to add an element in CoreData using swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an array of flash cards, which have a term and definition, and I want the option to add a card to an existing array of cards, but I'm having trouble. This is what I've tried but the error I get says `Cannot convert value of type 'Card' to expected type argument 'Cards'`

```
let card = Cards(context: context)
card.term = editTermField.text!
card.definition = editDefinitionField.text!
card.score = 0.0
cardArray.append(Card(term: card.term!, definition: card.definition!, score: card.score))
ad.saveContext()
```

Comment: You aren't giving us enough of your code, but fetchedCards is probably a `Set<Cards>`. You are expected to add a Cards object to it. But why do you have `Card` and `Cards`? Is there a relation between them (e.g. is Cards like a Deck?)?

Comment: If I think of Cards like a Deck. What you are doing is adding a card to a collection of decks -- that's why you are getting an error.

Comment: when I try to append to deck.cards it says its a get only property

Comment: You certainly don't need `fetchedCards.append(cardToAdd)` - You don't modify the result of a fetch.  You just add the new card to the context and then re-fetch if you want a new fetched result, but also can you explain the difference between your `Cards` entity and your `Card` entity?

Comment: Cards is a core data object, Card is a custom object. Both have the same attributes. but you can't use a core data object in the same way as a custom object, so I use create an array of Card coming from Cards

Comment: I'm sorry if this is confusing I just picked up on this project after a couple months off from it

Comment: see the post for updates I made to the code